# Crash writing simple WSO2/C++ web service client

Tags: c++, web-services, wso2

Has any been able to successfully run with a client using the [WSO2/C++ web](http://wso2.org/projects/wsf/cpp) services package?  I've tried just about everything I can think of yet every time I try to run a very simple client I get a crash.  Here's some sample code from one of their example programs...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WSRESTClient.h>
#include <OMElement.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <AxisFault.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace wso2wsf;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 WSRESTClient * sc = new WSRESTClient("http://localhost:9090/axis2/services/echo/echoString");
    try 
    {   
        sc->initializeClient("echo_rest.log", AXIS2_LOG_LEVEL_TRACE);
    }   
    catch (AxisFault & e)
    {   
        cout << endl << "Error: " << e << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    Options * op = sc->getOptions();
    op->setHTTPMethod(AXIS2_HTTP_GET);
    sc->setOptions(op);
    {
        OMNamespace * ns = new OMNamespace("http://ws.apache.org/axis2/services/echo", "ns1");
        OMElement * payload = new OMElement(NULL,"echoString", ns);
        OMElement * child = new OMElement(payload,"text", NULL);
        child->setText("Hello World!");
        cout << endl << "Request: " << payload << endl;
        OMElement * response;
        try
        {
            response = sc->request(payload, "http://ws.apache.org/axis2/c/samples/echo/soap_action");
            if (response)
            {
                cout << endl << "Response: " << response << endl;
            }
        }
        catch (AxisFault & e)
        {
            cout << endl << "Error: " << e << endl;
        }
        delete payload;
    }
    delete sc;

    return 0;
}
```

I get a crash every time at the point of the WRESTClient object construction.  It appears to be an issue somewhere in the WSO2 code but I don't get any error message indicating what the exact problem is. My next step will be to build against the source for WSO2 and step through the code which is crashing but I'm hoping someone has encountered this issue before and has some immediate feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered putting a try/catch-all block around the WRESTClient object construction? If you're core dumping on this line then the chances are that it's throwing an exception, and if you catch it then you might be able to get more useful error information out of that exception.

Other than that, time to break out the debugger as you suggested.